# How to ask Github Copilot Chat for translating .po file?

Tags: github-copilot

Is it possible to make Github Copilot Chat translating a .po file automatically ?
I use VisualStudio Code and Github Copilot Business version.
I notice that Github Copilot can produce suggestions for translating sentences when editing file directly.
But I want to know if a specific prompt exists for Copilot Chat in order to make it translating the entire file automatically ?